WorkItemRevision conditioned on WorkItems values
I want to bring the revisions of a workItem only if: the workItem is still open or ClosedDate >= 01/01/2023
But the field ChangedDate from Revisions is about the revision change.
I need: first filter Wis, after that bring the revisions.
Maybe Nested let?
Here is my code:

    let
        // URL base do OData
        Fonte = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/company/teamProject/_odata/v4.0-preview/", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
        WorkItems_table = Fonte{[Name="WorkItems",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    
        
        FilterClosedDate = Table.SelectRows(WorkItems_table,
            each ([ClosedDate] >= DateTime.AddZone( #datetime(2023, 1, 1,0,0,0), -3, 00 ) 
                or [ClosedDate] <> null
               
                )
        ),
        
        FilterWiType = Table.SelectRows(FilterClosedDate,
            each ([WorkItemType] = "Improvement"   
                or [WorkItemType] = "Data Query"
                or [WorkItemType] = "Data Fix"
                or [WorkItemType] = "Defect"
                or [WorkItemType] = "Support"
                )
        ),
    
        FilterState = Table.SelectRows(FilterWiType,
            each ([State] <> "Removed"
                or [State] <> "Rejected"
                or [State] <> "Expurgated"
         )
        ),
        //Aplicação de Filtro
        #"ExpandRevisions" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(FilterState, "Revisions", {"RevisedDate"}),
        // Expande os registros de BoardLocations
        #"Expand BoardLocations" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(ExpandRevisions, "BoardLocations", {"ColumnName", "IsDone"}),
    
        // Agrupa os dados por WorkItemId, ColumnName e IsDone e calcula a data mínima de ChangedDate
        #"Group by WorkItemId and BoardLocations" = Table.Group(
            #"Expand BoardLocations",
            {"WorkItemId", "ColumnName", "IsDone"},
            {{"MinChangedDate", each List.Min([ChangedDate]), type datetime}}
        ),
    
        // Seleciona as colunas necessárias
        #"Select Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(
            #"Group by WorkItemId and BoardLocations",
            {"WorkItemId", "ColumnName", "IsDone", "MinChangedDate"}
        ),
        #"Linhas Classificadas" = Table.Sort(#"Select Columns",{{"WorkItemId", Order.Ascending}})
    in
        #"ExpandRevisions"


But ExpandRevisions is not possible...
DataSource.Error: OData: Falha na solicitação: O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (400) Solicitação Incorreta. (VS403483: The query specified in the URI is not valid: VS403489: The Analytics Service doesn't support key or property navigation like WorkItems(Id) or WorkItem(Id)/AssignedTo. If you getting that error in PowerBI, please, rewrite your query to avoid incorrect folding that causes N+1 problem..)
Detalhes:
DataSourceKind=OData
DataSourcePath=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/company/teamProject/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems(73592)/Revisions
Url=https://analytics.dev.azure.com/company/teamProject/_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItems(73592)/Revisions
Update: I tried to create a function with my workItens and then apply in Revisions for SelectRows comparing workItemId, but it takes soooo long to return. Both tables has a lot of rows. I need an optimized solution.

Hi @Carol, have you tried to separately retrieve all revisions of the work item into a table, and finally merge two tables? Did it work for you?

There is the same error on my side when trying to expand revisions.

According to the error message, the Analytics Service doesn't support key or property navigation like WorkItems(Id) or WorkItem(Id)/AssignedTo.
You can try to separately retrieve all revisions of the work item into a table, and finally merge two tables. Refer to this blog Creating a Revision History in PowerBI from Azure DevOps data for the details.
